# Reading a lot of data from table (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:)

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I'm trying to create an app to show a list of students and their profiles
I wanted to store it in SQL Server to store the data outside the phone

Now when I try to get the data from the SQL Server table I get a

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:

How can I do it right?

My code:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList();
if (connection!=null){
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from STUDENT_TABLE;");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            //column 1 - last name, column 2 - name, column 3 - class 
            students.add(new Student(resultSet.getString(1),
                    resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(1)));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    text.setText(R.string.connection_is_null);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding statement.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

Comment: @Dren tried now, got this exception: `W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: The setFetchSize method requires a parameter value >= 0.`

Comment: Have you tried adding a limit to the query so it doesn't return too much data? You may want to look into pagination

Comment: Maybe don't `select *`, only select the columns you're interested in? There could be any number of varbinary columns or other large values that need to be transferred over the wire and stored in memory, even though you subsequently throw them away in your while loop.

Comment: thanks @AlwaysLearning , but i don't understand what do you mean? can you show me an example please? (i'm a beginner...)

Comment: `Select * from STUDENT_TABLE;` means select every column and every row from STUDENT_TABLE and bring it back over the wire to your local computer, where it has to be held in memory. You're then iterating over that result set and keeping only three columns' worth of information - but the computer still needs enough memory to hold the entire result set in the first place. It would be far more efficient, and less likely to run out of memory, if you only select the data you need, e.g.: `select last_name, name, class from STUDENT_TABLE;`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you, but it's still very slow... i decided to go with [Firebase](https://www.google.com/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjxrPi5xP7uAhVF7u0KHX1qAD4YABAAGgJkZw&sig=AOD64_15zyQhOqqztJMB8FOfPWIKlDAbEA&q&adurl&ved=2ahUKEwiKpPG5xP7uAhUjpHEKHQnxAYMQ0Qx6BAgLEAE), thank you guys anyway...